# Sci-fi book where main characters play multidimensonal chess aboard a spacecraft

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship

Humans travelling in space play multidimensional chess games (7 dimensions?). One of the female characters may have a name "stormy..." or similar. I read it in italian translation as a kid at the library about 40 years ago.

Comment: Is there any more to the story besides chess games in space? Does the spaceship arrive anywhere, or is the whole story in space? Is the ship a passenger liner, a colonization ship, an exploration ship, a warship?

Comment: Could it be "Starman Jones"? He plays (only) three dimensional chess with a girl called Eldreth (Ellie) Coburn.

Comment: Space travellers playing higher dimensional chess has been a common trope since Heinlein's *Starman Jones* was published in 1953. (Ninja'd by Clara)

Comment: Could it possibly have been a Star Trek novel?   One of them has McCoy beating Spock at the newly invented game 4-Dimensional chess. That's basically the only thing I remember about the book,  I can't tell if it had a woman named Stormy. Date's about right.   https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/My_Enemy,_My_Ally

Comment: Starman Jones does not seem correct. Star Trek for sure is not. I do not recall the purpose of the trip but I think the chess playing had something to do with the navigation of the spaceship.

Comment: I don't know about a science fiction book, but a prominent politician who "played 3-dimensional chess" and had a girlfriend named Stormy comes to mind.

Answer (score 12):

It's only a partial match, as the chess games were three-dimensional (instead of 7-dimensional), and as far as I can tell none of the female characters had a name like "Stormy", but I'd propose "[Starman Jones](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1121)" by Robert Heinlein. The Italian translation was published in 1970, which more or less agrees with reading it 40 years ago.

The game is often played by astrogators and computermen who do multidimensional space navigation, and ordinary chess is referred to rather disparagingly as "flat chess". The main character, Max Jones, plays 3D chess with one of the passengers aboard the space liner, Eldreth Coburn, known as Ellie. A brief mention is also made of 4-dimensional chess, which is played by *real* players:

> “It's just a matter of holding in your mind one more spatial
> relationship.”

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think there is a scene in Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy where Trillian plays 3D chess on the bridge of the Heart of Gold with someone (Zaphod? Marvin?). The book came out in 1979 and is a sci-fi classic, so it could fit.

Comment: Certainly not the Hitchhiker... it was a short book, linear, not a big blockbuster.

Comment: @mangiumicro My hardback copy of HHGTTG is about 200 pages long.